# Firebug lite console.log not showing

Tags: javascript, firebug-lite

I'm using Firebug lite, but it seems it doesn't work like is should.

I include it in my app like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#overrideConsole=true,startInNewWindow=false,startOpened=false,enableTrace=false">
     </script>
```

and Firebug opens in new window, console is not working (not getting msg from app) and trace is on. It looks like this options are not valid.

What could I be doing wrong here?

EDIT: It also doesn't output any javascript errors like undefined is not a function

Comment: I have JxBrower embedded in Java swing app and I need something to help me debug.

Comment: Same here with JavaFX/Dukescript

Comment: I managed to solve this - I placed firebug to local server and called it like this:
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/firebuglite/libs/firebug-lite.js">
            {
                overrideConsole: true,
                startInNewWindow: true,
                startOpened: true,
                enableTrace: false
            }
        </script>